# this.props.xxx is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've found a few other posts with similar errors and I've already ruled out:

The function is correctly imported in curly braces

The action is dispatched

The file path is correct

It must just be some silly mistake but Ive been looking at it for ages and cannot seem to find it, and help appreciated!

action:

```
export const deleteRow = (rowId) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: "LOADING_UI" });
  axios
    .delete(`/row/${rowId}`)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "DELETE_ROW",
        payload: res.data,
      });
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_ERRORS",
        payload: err.response.data,
      });
    });
};
```

component:

```
export class MyDelete extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };
  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
  handleDelete = () => {
    this.props.deleteRow(this.props.rowId);
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>
          <HighlightOffIcon color="primary" />
        </Button>
        <Dialog
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          fullWidth
          maxWidth="sm"
        >
          <DialogTitle>Are you sure you want to delete this row ?</DialogTitle>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.handleDelete} color="secondary">
              Delete
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

MyDelete.propTypes = {
  deleteRow: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  rowId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, { deleteRow })(MyDelete);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using connect with [object shorthand form](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#object-shorthand-form), it expects each field to be an [action creator](https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/glossary#action-creator), and binds each field to dispatch.

Your function deleteRow is not an action creator, so instead you should not use object shorthand form and directly use **dispatch**:

```
export class MyDelete extends Component {
 //...
 deleteRow = (rowId) => {
  this.props.dispatch({ type: "LOADING_UI" });
  axios.delete(...)
 }
 //...
}

export default connect()(MyDelete);
```

Comment: This leads to 'this.props.dispatch is not a function'

Comment: For this.props.dispatch to be available you need to move *deleteRow* inside your class definition. Otherwise you can pass *this.props.dispatch* as an argument along *rowId* in *handleDelete*

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `mapDispatchToProps` function approach instead of **object shorthand form** like so :-

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
  return {
  deleteRow:(rowId)=>dispatch(deleteRow(rowId));
  }
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyDelete);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error with this unfortunately